# YouTube V3 Api not configured

Tags: youtube-api

Trying to access Youtube v3 api using the following link:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=funny& key=AIzaSyDFiabJG7l7aLfdvsLL1_DqKbZipKLvaI4
```

which returns

```
 {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

The Google Cloud Console  is billing enable account for the registered app with a Browser Key as follows;

Access data that comes from a browser, and that is not associated with an account
Api Key 
AIzaSyDFiabJG7l7aLfdvsLL1_DqKbZipKLvaI4
Allowed referrers - Any referrer is allowed.
Activated on
Dec 3, 2013 11:11 PM

What are the factors which would cause this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't enabled access for "YouTube Data API v3" on your project.
Following procedure may solve your issue:

1. Access to [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console#/project)
2. Select your project which uses YouTube Data API v3
3. Navigate to "APIs & auth" > "APIs", and toggle the switch next to API name.

Answer (score 2):

Any referer allowed

Please click Edit Allowed Refers and the removed the bundle id (com.something) and again click update .
And then use same api key hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, even with the project properly configured it gives the same error. In this case you may need to try one of the following:

- Regenerate the key
- Edit the allowed referrers
- Remove any referrers altogether (if it complies with your project requirements, of course)
- Use a Server Key instead of a Browser Key

[See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t)