# Google Translate API integration in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-translate

I am trying to do a simple translation using `Google Translate` in my iOS app but as i call the url, i am getting the following error in response…

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I couldn't find anything close to any solution of this issue.. Please can anyone help here. thanks in advance…

Comment: Answer by iPatel should be the right one. I added billing settings and it started working. Its not a bug. The error might have been clearer though.

Comment: i did add the billing info and all other required information but still it would't work based on `bundleId`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after some detailed searching and RnD, i found out that `Google Translate API` doesn't work with `Bundle Identifier` in **iOS**.. People have filed it as a bug on google forums.. So anyone trying hard to solve this can stop the efforts till it is solved..

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **ON** for the Google Translate API.

Read 3rd step of setup of [Getting Started link.](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started)

> In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Google Translate API.

And make sure have to enable billing?

> Important: Google Translate API v2 requires billing information for all accounts before you can start using the service.

And also have to set [API key in proper way?](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#auth)

Comment: **setDeveloperKey** in iOS app…?

Comment: @AhmedZ. - look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t

Answer (score 0):

Since bundle id is optional for Key. So you can escape adding bundle id and enable the billing on. It will work. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you hadn't add the Credit card detail with your Google Cloud account, as rules has changed in which you need to add credit card details if you use Google translate api.