# Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project

Tags: youtube-api, google-api

I am getting the same error thats solution is suggested in below answer. But not able to find the "Referers" option under my project.

[Getting Error 403: Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is called

"Any IP allowed"

[image: Here is the image to help you find it]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its giving me the results now.

Comment: Great, i am happy that i was able to help!