# How to get email and profile information upon successful login to google

Tags: javascript, api, email, google-api, google-plus

I have successfully authenticedated to google using the scopes:

```
 var scopes=['email','profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
```

I use this to try and read the user's email and profile:

```
function getEmail(resp)
{
  var email,isFound=false;
  console.log(resp);
  for(var i=0;i<resp.emails.length && !isFound;i++)
  {
    if(resp.emails[i].type==='account')
    {
        email=resp.emails[i].value;
        isFound=true
    }   
   }
   return email;    
 }

function getProfile(resp)
{
    console.log(resp);
    console.log("Retrieved profile for "+resp.displayName);
}

function handleResponse(resp)
{
    var email=getEmail(resp);
    var profile=getProfile(resp);
}
```

Inside handleAuthResult I call:

```
gapi.client.load('plus','v1',function(){
    //request profile information
    var request=gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        'userid':'me',
    });
    //execute the request
    request.execute(handleResponse);

});
```

Instead of the user's email and the profile,I get the following response:

```
{
"code": 403,
"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
"data": [
    {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
        "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
    }
],
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
    "data": [
        {
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
            "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I turned on the `Google+ API` in the `Google API Console` to get this:

```
{
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found",
"data": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
],
"error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t

Comment: @Sid I am using any referrer allowed in the Referrers setting.

Comment: that question contains other solutions. Did you try those?

Comment: @Sid i tried activating the Google+ API and the Contacts API to no avail

Comment: @Sid I used a different API key and it workd for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `userid` parameter is case-sensitive and should be `userId` instead.

I tested and using `userid` results in the 404 error message you are seeing while `userId` works for me. Not a very useful error message in this case...

Comment: @Scarygemi I get a 403 asking me to `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.`I have the `Drive API`,the `Google+ API` and `Contacts API` active,what am i missing here