# getting google contacts using shuttlecloud

Tags: perl, http, google-api, google-oauth

I can not get the google user's contacts using shuttlecloud. I did everything according to the shuttlecloud and google documentation. I got a user's contact with shuttlecloud using password-based authentication(mail.ru for example). I create url and put it to browser `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http://localhost:80&response_type=code&client_id=my_id.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly&access_type=offline`

I get the code and copy to script:

```
my $url = 'https://demo.api.shuttlecloud.com/beta/load';
my $auth_url = 'https://demo.api.shuttlecloud.com/beta/auth/capabilities';
my $appid = 'my_shuttlecloud_id';
my $ts = int(time);
my $secret = 'my_shuttlecloud_secret';
my $sig = sha256_hex("{".$appid.":".$secret.":".$ts."}");
my $url_tok = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token';
my $code = '4/GmVQi8AgNzajSo0mTudUBumjHyHhhb9EBxN8ufG6z34.QjE7Q6MjmUweWmFiZwPfH01FreiwmwI';
my $id = 'my_google_id';
my $sec = 'my_google_secret';
my $redirect = 'http://localhost:80';
my $grant_type = 'authorization_code';

my $response = $ua->request(POST $url_tok,
       Content_Type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       Content      => [ code  => $code,
                         redirect_uri => $redirect,
                         client_id => $id,
                         client_secret => $sec,
                         grant_type   => $grant_type,
                       ]);
my $cod = $response->content;
my $decoded_json = decode_json( $cod );
my $token = @{$decoded_json}{'access_token'};
my $email = 'my_google_email@gmail.com';
my $data = '{
    "contactsextraction": {
        "sourceaccount": {
            "userid": {
                        "email": "'.$email.'"
            },
            "auth": {
            "3loauth": "'.$token.'"
            }
        }
    }
}';

$url = $url."?appid=".$appid."&ts=".$ts."&sig=".$sig;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content($data);
my $resp = $ua->request($req);
my $message;
if ($resp->is_success) {
    $message = $resp->decoded_content;
}
else {
    print "error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
$decoded_json = decode_json( $message );
my $ft_url = @{$decoded_json}{'fetchurl'};
$ft_url = $ft_url."?appid=".$appid."&ts=".$ts."&sig=".$sig;
sleep 5;
$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $ft_url);
$resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    $message = $resp->decoded_content;
}
else {
    print "error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
$decoded_json = decode_json( $message );
print Dumper ($decoded_json);
```

I receive from shuttlecloud json: `'status' => 'STARTED'` without contacts.
When i create token using `OAuth 2.0 Playground` and paste to script - all works. Following from this, i do not correctly create access token, but can not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is ridiculous and stupid. I did not know that the API must be activated in the Google console. You can see how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t).

Answer (score 1):

in the documentation it says:

> This request returns the status of the job and the extracted contacts
>   up to that point in time from the account.
>
> The server provides a URL from which the real-time progress can be
>   retrieved.

You need to do polling to retrieve the contacts until they are ready. It is quite fast, usually some seconds, but not instant. Try to do the contacts fetch request in a loop waiting 1 second for example between each request and you should obtain all the contacts.

Comment: I know this, but status hangs in the `STARTED` state.

Comment: Could you please copy&paste the code you use to do the polling?