# youTube Api key throwing error on execution

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hi dears i am working on youtube api/v3. I created an Api key(not browser key). I am enabling all necessary API's on my account.But i am experiencing this error i am posting here.

```html
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
 }
```

this is my query URL [url](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=GoogleDevelopers&key=AIzaSyDX4tM7YT4rIocx2nWw0T2ijiysutFDOv0) 
any help regarding my question will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to fetch by the call ? Some more context would be helpful

Comment: I am trying to get most popular list from youtube

Comment: @AbKDs please check my query now in comment

Comment: It's working right ? It shows the data when I click your new query

Comment: first remove your api key (I mean remove the exact url) from the question just write the structure of the url and show the error message. You should never reveal api keys

Comment: got it Sir. next time will be careful. and this is my url. https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&key=

Comment: And my error is same as posted in question

Comment: I am looking for solution. Give me some time

Comment: Could you try the solutions given on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t?Wi5BVbnHB4PJmAXW14HgBQ&ved=0CEcQFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNFthRH1b0pckt6Nzn5Ywknufjc7Fg

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Developers Console > API Manager > Credentials. Check the section **Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)**.

Comment: can you please send me the link because i am not getting this option.(Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites))

Comment: I got this. Its empty