# Node.js - Get google results in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-api

I'm iterating over 2 arrays in order to construct google searches that return true if any search results contain content from both arrays. Using Node.js, what's the best way to get consumable json results?

```
module.exports = function(context, cb) {
    var google = require('googleapis');
    var request = require('request');
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='+context.data.key+'&cx='+context.data.cx+'&q=lectures';
    console.log(url);
    request(url,function(error, response, result){
        if(!error){
            console.log(result);
            cb(null, result);
        }
    });
};
```

which gives the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (CustomSearch API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (CustomSearch API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
```

This is close but not a duplicate of [Getting Error 403: Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Error 403: Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NODE.JS* Convert GTFS file into json. 
*Add File Content in mongoDB in json format*

```js
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var GtfsRealtimeBindings = require('gtfs-realtime-bindings');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var jsonData

var requestSettings = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=948444f7ec34a8c264a22d2b044d88d6&feed_id=1',
    encoding: null
};

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    request(requestSettings, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            jsonData = GtfsRealtimeBindings.FeedMessage.decode(body);
            // jsonData.entity.forEach(function (entity) {
            //     if (entity.trip_update) {
            res.send(jsonData);
            //     }
            // });
            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var dbo = db.db("mydb");
                dbo.collection("customers").insertMany(jsonData.entity, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
                    db.close();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});





app.listen(3010, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3010!'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party service like [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com) to scrape Google and get back structured JSON.

Example using the [Node.js library](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-nodejs):

```
var gsr = require('GoogleSearchResults')
let serp = new gsr.GoogleSearchResults("demo")
serp.json({
 q: "Coffee", 
 location: "Portland"
}, (result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to enable the api here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch/overview?project=ai-query

Thanks @djechlin for pointing to near-duplicate answer.